# Filebeat on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, windows-server-2012, filebeat

I am using Filebeat > Logstash > Elasticsearch > Kibana to parse and analyse logs basically Java Stack Trace and other Logs.

Here is YML for Filebeat

```
filebeat:
  prospectors:
    -
      paths:
        - C:\logs\OCR\example.log
      input_type: log
      #document_type: UAT_EXAMPLE
      exclude_lines: [".+DEBUG"]
      multiline:
         pattern: ".+(ERROR|INFO)"
         negate: true
         match: after
      fields:
         app_name: EXAMPLE_APP
         environment: UAT
      fields_under_root: true
      #force_close_files: true
      spool_size: 2048
      #publish_async: true
      #scan_frequency: 10s
      #close_older: 2h

output:
  logstash:
    host: "10.0.64.14"
    port: 5044
    index: filebeat
    timeout: 5
    reconnect_interval: 3
    bulk_max_size: 2048

shipper:
 tags: ["ABC_Engine", "UAT_EXAMPLE"]
 queue_size: 1000

###  Enable logging of the filebeat
logging:
  level: warning
  to_files: true
  files:
    path: c:\logs\
    name: mybeat.log
    rotateeverybytes: 20485760 # = 20MB
    keepfiles: 7
```

Enable logging of the filebeat is also not working on windows. Let me know if I am missing anything here.

```
logging:
   level: warning
   to_files: true
   files:
      path: c:\logs\
      name: mybeat.log
      rotateeverybytes: 20485760 # = 20MB
      keepfiles: 7
```

Problem - the Filebeat is not able to send logs to logstash at times, some times it start running shipping but sometimes it doesn't.
Although If I use "test.log" as a prospector and save logs locally on disk via below config it works well.

Writing Files to local File to Check the output. I have tried "file" output and "logstash" output one by one.

```
output:
file:
path: c:\logs\
filename: filebeat
rotate_every_kb: 100000
number_of_files: 7
```

Also, The things mostly run when I am using command Line:

```
.\filebeat.exe -c filebeat.yml -e -v
```

Kindly assist with the correct config for Windows.

The log file "example.log" is getting rotated on every 30 MB of size.

I am not very sure to use the below attributes and how they will function with Filebeat on Windows.

"close_older"
"ignore_older"
"Logging"

Answer (score 1):

output to logstash :

comment elasticsearch line

then

```
logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
   hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
```

keep []

and config for log in debug mode for example

```
logging:
# Send all logging output to syslog. On Windows default is false, otherwise
# default is true.
#to_syslog: true

# Write all logging output to files. Beats automatically rotate files if      rotateeverybytes
# limit is reached.
#to_files: false

# To enable logging to files, to_files option has to be set to true
 files:
# The directory where the log files will written to.
#path: /var/log/mybeat
path: c:\PROGRA~1/filebeat

# The name of the files where the logs are written to.
name: filebeat.log

# Configure log file size limit. If limit is reached, log file will be
# automatically rotated
rotateeverybytes: 10485760 # = 10MB

# Number of rotated log files to keep. Oldest files will be deleted first.
#keepfiles: 7

# Enable debug output for selected components. To enable all selectors use    ["*"]
# Other available selectors are beat, publish, service
# Multiple selectors can be chained.
#selectors: [ ]

# Sets log level. The default log level is error.
# Available log levels are: critical, error, warning, info, debug
 level: debug
```

LOGGING is in LOGGING part, output is logstash or elastic search, if you want know you can install as service go to the elastic.co website :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-installation.html